# Exclude packages from Jacoco report using gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: java, junit, devops, gitlab-ci, jacoco

I want to exclude some packages from my jacoco coverage report.
I have excluded the packages in the pom.xml where I have added the jacoco plugin and it's working fine, I cannot see the excluded package in the report as expected.

```
      <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/utilities/**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
      </configuration>
```

The same thing I wanted to do in the below git-ci.yml file for coverage stage.

```
 coverage:
  stage: coverage
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test jacoco:report
    - cat target/site/jacoco/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%' | sed 's/<.*>/ /; s/Total/Jacoco Coverage Total:/'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml


cat target/site/jacoco/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%' | sed 's/<.*>/ /; s/Total/Jacoco Coverage Total:/' -- output of this is percentage coverage of entire classes in my project.
```

I am not sure how to achieve this using gitlab-ci?

Comment: This has been resolved by adding exclude in pom.xml only for goal: "report"
we do not need to add the same exclusion in gitlab-ci.yml file, the report will be generated according to the plugin configuration.